# Example of uncountable set, $A$ of cardinals such that $\bigcup A$ is countable

Tags: set-theory

My question is whether there exists an uncountable set $A$ of cardinals such that $\bigcup A=\{x |\exists a\in A \wedge x\in a\}$ is countable.

For example, could I take $A=\{\aleph_\alpha|\alpha <2^{\aleph_0}\}$?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no such thing. If $A$ is a set of ordinals, so in particular if it a set of cardinals, $\bigcup A$ is simply $\sup A$.

If $A$ is an uncountable set of *cardinals*, then *most* of its elements are themselves uncountable. It follows that $\bigcup A=\sup A$ is at least as large as some uncountable cardinal. So it has to be uncountable as well.

Comment: Then it's indeed possible. Take $\alpha$ to be your favourite uncountable ordinal whose cofinality is countable, then $\{\aleph_\xi\mid\xi<\alpha\}$ is such a set, since its supremum is $\aleph_\alpha$.